# Using video As background, not mobile responsive

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

ok,

```js
<s.Container
                  style={
                    {
                      // width: 100,
                      // padding: 24,
                      // backgroundSize: "2550px",
                    }
                  }
                >
                  <StyledVid
                    src={Insert}
                    type="video/mp4"
                    autoPlay
                    loop
                    muted
                    playsInline
                    style={
                      {
                        // position: "absolute",
                        // width: "100%",
                        // left: "50%",
                        // top: "50%",
                        // height: "100vh",
                        // objectFit: "cover",
                        // transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                        // zIndex: "-1",
                        // overflow: "hidden",
                        // objectFit: "cover",
                        // width: "100vw",
                        // height: "100vh",
                        // position: "fixed",
                        // top: "0",
                        // left: "0",
                      }
                    }
                  />
                </s.Container>
```

```css
export const StyledVid = styled.video`
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    /* width: 250px; */
  }
  /* @media (min-width: 900px) {
    width: 250px;
  } */
  /* @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    width: 300px;
  } */
`;
```

so I'm trying to create a responsive background with a video that is 1440 x 1025. Now in mobile view, the background only shows the middle. is my CSS off?

Thanks
ps The file format is in.mp4 for the background. and I want it to sill the whole screen.

Comment: Can you show us the wrapper component?

Comment: `export const ResponsiveWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretched;
  align-items: stretched;
  width: 100%;
  @media (min-width: 1345px) {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
`;`

Comment: Not difficult to make a responsive video background, but you have to accept some cropping if you want to fill the entire background.  Device screen ratios will rarely perfectly match the video.